# Looking for flashcard software with ability “to show card in a few seconds” like Biscuit app have

Tags: windows, osx

I'm looking for any software (both Mac or Windows are okay) like [Biscuit flashcard app](https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/biscuit-bisuketto-ci-shu-dan/id526273460?mt=8) that has ability to show card in a few seconds (not in a blink though) and of course, to make flashcard by myself.

I got many flashcard apps in Google but I don't like with their SRS methods. I don't like rating of "how do you remember" with 0 (not sure) to 5 (very sure). I also don't like many UI of apps there because they're not beautiful and simple as Biscuit app have and Biscuit doesn't have its desktop version (only Chrome extension).

I want to memorize many definitions from my Biology book.

As far as I know, only Biscuit has this ability. Maybe I need to make small software from scratch and someone could guide me to make the software. I also like make prototype design (I have many designs for specific task for productivity reason) but I get struggle for the coding/programming.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not absolutely certain if it has the exact capability to automatically show the card after a few seconds but you might want to take a look at [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/index.html) as it is available on just about everything and has a pretty large number of features on every platform.